# Cannot create web documentation from on_flow_end callback

Tags: origen-sdk

I'm trying to setup origen to automatically generate web documentation after generating a flow with the `origen p` command, so I added the following callback:

```
def on_flow_end(options)
  OrigenDocHelpers.generate_flow_docs layout: "#{Origen.root}/templates/web/layouts/_basic.html.erb", tab: :flows do |d|
    d.page  flow: "#{options[:test_module]}_flow".to_sym,
            name: "#{options[:test_module].to_s.upcase} Flow",
            target: "#{Origen.target.name}.rb"  
  end
end
```

This causes an error when building the flow page:

```
[INFO]       14.641[0.005]   || Building flow page: /users/chorton/osdk/ppekit/web/content/flows/pcie_flow.md

COMPLETE CALL STACK
-------------------
Can't find: partials/_navbar.html
/home/chorton/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7bf48a874995/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:137:in `clean_path_to'
/home/chorton/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7bf48a874995/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:226:in `rescue in clean_path_to_sub_template'
/home/chorton/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7bf48a874995/lib/origen/file_handler.rb:213:in `clean_path_to_sub_template'
/home/chorton/.origen/gems/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/origen-7bf48a874995/lib/origen/generator/renderer.rb:8:in `render'
(erb):4:in `_get_binding'
```

There is no error if I separately call `origen p` (without the added callback) and then run:

`origen web compile --remote --api`

Is it possible to combine the two into one command with a callback like I'm trying to do or is it necessary for `origen web compile` to be called after `origen p`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem like a bug, please open a ticket for it here if you cannot get it resolved - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/issues

I would say that the convention normally used to do this is to hook into the `after_web_site_compile` callback in your `config/application.rb`.

Here is an example:

```rb
# config/application.rb

def after_web_site_compile(options)
  # Build the test flow docs
  Origen.environment.temporary = 'v93k.rb'
  # Generate the program for the target(s) you want to document
  %w(device_a device_b).each do |target|
    Origen.target.temporary = "#{target}.rb"
    Origen.app.runner.launch action: :program,
                             files:  'program/full.list' # Or whatever file arg you pass to 'origen p'

    OrigenDocHelpers.generate_flow_docs layout: "#{Origen.root}/templates/web/layouts/_basic.html.erb", tab: :flows do |d|
      d.page flow: "#{options[:test_module]}_flow".to_sym,
             name: "#{options[:test_module].to_s.upcase} Flow",
           target: "#{target}.rb"  
    end
  end
end
```